# get disk io per process without SU at linux

Tags: linux, bash, process, io, disk

I made a bash script that reads per process cpu, mem, etc and I want also to read the disk I/O bytes/s and also I/O transactions for that process.

From /proc/pid from io file I can get the information I want from syscr, syscw, read_bytes and write_bytes fields. But io file is readable from root only and I want something without super user rights.

Tried iotop but also need SU, iostat doesn't display per process. Top doesn't gives me transactions, so....

Is there any other way that I can take these numbers? Either from the system or from another utility.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Could you share the results of your work for getting process cpu,mem, etc? I extremely need that!!! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you still need this?

Comment: @Volodymyr It's been a long but tell me where to upload the script so I can give it to you if you still need this.

Comment: @C Ts you can paste it here: http://pastebin.com/ Thanks!